# How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?

Tags: unity, launcher

This has been an issue for me with Unity since its release.
I'd like to make the the launcher auto-hide. Especially on Netbooks, where screens are small, the launcher is quite wide, making it difficult to properly display some websites and other apps.
How can I configure the auto-hide behavior?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## 11.04 & 11.10

The Unity launcher has an auto-hide option that is enabled by default. Lee's [answer has the details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/will-the-unity-launcher-auto-hide/31418#31418). It has a few options:

- Never - The launcher will never hide.
- Autohide - The launcher will hide automatically based on time.
- Dodge Windows - The launcher will hide when a window would overlay it.
- Dodge Active Window - The launcher will hide only when an active window would overlay it.

This question has information on how to configure the different modes of Unity:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-the-unity-desktop-plugin)

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist on 14.04.

Comment: @jzc This is the answer you want: http://askubuntu.com/a/106673/235

Comment: **I was looking for the additional options, Dodge Windows and Dodge Active Window.**

The answer you linked states: *Unlike previous versions of Ubuntu, the dodge windows option has been removed due to User testing that showed that this form of autohiding caused confusion.* (From the answer)

Answer (score 56):

## 12.04 and later - Unity

The Unity Launcher auto-hide option is now a *System Setting - Appearance* option:
By default, auto-hide is switched off - in previous versions of Ubuntu these behaviour was reverse.

[image]

From the *Behaviour* tab you have the option to switch-on autohiding of the Launcher and using the slide-bar to control the responsiveness to the reveal of the launcher.

[image]

You can use the *Reveal Location* radio-buttons to indicate where you need to position your mouse to reveal the launcher.

The option to switch on autohiding and controlling the hotspot location (left edge/top left corner) is on the *Behaviour* tab.

Unlike previous versions of Ubuntu, the dodge windows option has been removed due to User testing that showed that this form of autohiding caused confusion.

## 12.04 & Unity-2D

The Unity-2D Launcher delay is now a *System Setting - Appearance* option:

[image]

From the *Behaviour* tab you have the option to switch-on autohiding of the Launcher and by clicking the *Low/High* buttons to control the responsiveness to the reveal of the launcher.

[image]

You can use the *Reveal Location* radio-buttons to indicate where you need to position your mouse to reveal the launcher.

By default the auto-hide nature is toggled *off* meaning the launcher is permanently visible.

---

Linked Question:

- [Shortcut to change Launcher 'Hide' setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41241/shortcut-to-change-launcher-hide-setting)

Answer (score 35):

## 11.04 & 11.10

You can disable the autohide feature of the Unity launcher by following these simple steps:

> WARNING: CCSM is an advanced tool and using it *may* break your Unity.
> To avoid this, follow the steps *exactly as mentioned here*

- Install the CompizConfig Settings Manager package via the Ubuntu Software Centre

[image: Installing the Compiz settings manager]

- Once installed, open the settings manager and scroll down until you see the 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' which is located in the Desktop category.

[image: The Compiz settings manager]

- Set 'Hide Launcher' to 'Never'.

[image: Changing the Launcher autohide settings]

- The settings will have automatically applied and the launcher will now be locked in place.

Comment: The Compiz Config Settings Manager **[can break things](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)** See the [answer of jackocnr](http://askubuntu.com/a/43708/28323) to learn how to do this with standard gnome means.

Comment: This question was obviously answered before the launcher changes made in Unity.

Comment: dodge windows would be nice. I got back to Unity (Ubuntu 16.04) and i miss this option. I want autohide but not when I am on desktop.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't have Compiz Config installed, you can still do this very easily.
 Launch `gconf-editor` by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing it and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
 Navigate to `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options` and then set `launcher_hide_mode` to `0`.

Answer (score 15):

With Compiz Config (ccsm) installed, go to the `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, now you will see a drop-down menu next to the words `Hide Launcher`, click on the drop down menu and select `Never` and that is it, Unity launcher will no longer hide.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: Well, it always shows the launcher now, but windows get maximised behind it. Can that be fixed?

Comment: Oh, and on dual monitors, windows on the secondary screen maximise very strangely (full height, 20 px wide, on the edge)

Comment: I've "fixed" both issues by picking the left monitor as the primary, instead of the right, which it apparently can't handle very well.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom, how do you make a monitor primary?

Comment: @James McMahon With the Nvidia config tool

Comment: Is there no way to do it on an intel integrated card?

Comment: @scouser I've done that already, and checked with the gconf-editor, restarted the system but the launcher keeps on hiding. Ubuntu runs in a VM on my right side monitor, and the mouse crosses over to the host OS from the left edge. Everytime I move between OS's the launcher appears. I have tried changind the edge, but still of no avail

Comment: The Compiz Config Settings Manager **[can break things](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)** See the [answer of jackocnr](http://askubuntu.com/a/43708/28323) to learn how to do this with standard gnome means.

Answer (score 4):

**16.04 CLI one liner**

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
```

`0` is the default value for auto-hide off.

Found with:

```
dconf watch /
```

then changing it from GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can auto-hide the Unity Launcher. Follow the below steps to do so.

- First open the **System Setting**.
  [image: system setting]
- Now Click on **Appearance** icon in Personal group.
- Now a window similar to below one can be seen.
  [image: appearance window]
- You can see that the **auto-hide** feature is turned **OFF** by default in my version(**16.04**).
- You are there! Click on the toggle switch to turned the feature **ON**.

> You can see that **Unity-Launcher** auto-hides when cursor is off from it.
>
> You can do the same in Ubuntu versions above **12.04**

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to edit the source & rebuild unity.  Haven't checked this in some time, (natty), bit I believe it;s defined in unity/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherHideMachine.cpp, possibly here (this is from unity-5.2 source

_hide_delay_timeout_length = `750`;

Answer (score 0):

## 17.10

In Ubuntu 17.10, open Settings (can press windows/super key and search for settings) and then toggle the Auto-hide the Dock option under Dock.

[image: Dock Settings]

Comment: Since upgrading to 18.10, the launcher no longer hides (not auto-hide) when the screen locks.