# Will the launcher use Intellihide by default?

Tags: unity, 11.04, launcher

I've found Unity's new Intellihide mode extremely useful, and would like to know if it's planned to be set by default or, by the contrary, the panel will be shown unless you set it manually.

Comment: Related but not a duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/will-the-unity-launcher-auto-hide

Comment: Is there actually intellihide? Because as far as I know from testing there only is autohide. This means that if you have a small window focused but there is a large one filling the whole screen in the background the launcher is still hidden. It would be much better if it would not be.

Answer (score 7):

The current plan is that it will be intelli-hide for large screens, fixed in place for netbooks, with an option to change it. That might well be changed to be intelli-hide for all devices by release, based on user testing as the implementation matures.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely result is that there will be an easy and obvious way to turn hiding of the launcher on and off. The starting state will be of little consequence due to this. If I had to guess, I would guess on by default.

Answer (score 0):

The User Interface Freeze is on March 2011, before then it can be changed several times so it is impossible to know what the team will decide at the end.

Comment: On the other hand, the team could have a plan, and someone could know the plan and answer the question. ;-)