# How to make the Unity launcher always visible?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

Is there a possibility to make Unity dock always visible on the left? Its current behaviour - hiding and showing, drives me insane :)