# How to never hide Unity Launcher? (using CCSM didn't work)

Tags: unity, ccsm

I've just installed Ubuntu 32-bit in a VM.  I've downloaded CCSM from the Software Center, set "Hide Launcher" to "Never", but it still disappears, what can I do?

Also, changing the icon size doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You might have to log out and log back in again. Also, your title says you want to hide the launcher, but your question seems like you want it to always show.

Comment: @Curyous - are you sure you are using unity 3d? CCSM doesnt work for Unity 2d - http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: Thanks @fossfreedom for pointing that out, it is Unity 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to make the Unity launcher always visible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35963/how-to-make-the-unity-launcher-always-visible)

> Launch gconf-editor by hitting F2 and then typing it and hitting Enter. Navigate to /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options and then set launcher_hide_mode to 0

Comment: Turns out I had Unity 2D so had to go to gconf-editor > desktop > unity-2D, which doesn't have as many settings.  From http://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d