# How do I prevent an application from obscuring the launcher when it is maximized?

Tags: 11.10, launcher

I want to configure my Unity desktop in Oneiric so that:

1. The launcher is never hidden.
2. When I maximize an application, it fills the visible workspace except for the launcher and the panel.

Currently, when I get the launcher to "Never" hide, and I maximize an application window, it "hides under" the launcher which requires me to manually resize it.

Is there a way for me to configure my desktop so that maximized windows don'd "hind under" or "obscure over" my launcher?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 1):

Please see question: [How to make the Unity launcher always visible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35963/how-to-make-the-unity-launcher-always-visible)

Basically you need to set the Ubuntu Unity Plugin's **Hide Launcher** option to **Never**. It can be set by using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

As for your comment that windows hide under the Launcher, this does not seem to happen to me. I've done a few tests and it seems to be working.