# How can I set up that the menu bar on the left is always shown?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

Hey,

I alway will see may menu bar on the left site. So I can switch faster between programms. In the Ubuntu Netbookremix 10.04 it was no prblem. But now the status bar is hide by default and i cant find a way to change it.
so is there a way to change?

Answer (score 1):

Install CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) from the Software Center. Open it and find the Unity plugin. There's a section in the Unity settings called Hide Launcher which is set to "Dodge Windows" by default. You can set it to "Never"