# Shortcut to change Launcher 'Hide' setting

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

When I'm working on my laptop I have periods that I am only using a couple of programs, so the default intellihide setting of the Launcher ('Dodge windows') is very handy. But I also have periods that I have to switch very often between programs, and then I find it very useful (and better for my workflow) that the Launcher doesn't hide.

Now, every time I wan't to switch I have to open CCSM and change the setting (Unity plugin -> Hide Launcher), but it would be easier if I could use a shortcut for it. So my question:

**Is there a way to create a shortcut to switch between (or change) the two settings of Compiz?**

I thought of command line interface to compiz, but I couldn't directly find something like that.

Comment: Command line for changing Compiz settings: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus But coding a switch for this you need someone else ;) (maybe leave a q on their wiki?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" 2
```

to set the launcher hide mode to "Dodge Windows", and

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" 0
```

to set it to never hide.

The mode numbers are:

- 0 - Never
- 1 - Autohide
- 2 - Dodge Windows
- 3 - Dodge Active Window

You can make this a switch by just calling (the value must be 2 or 0 before):

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" $((2 - $(gconftool-2 --get "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode")))
```

You then would create a new keybinding (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gnome-keybinding-properties`) with the command being:

```
/bin/bash -c "gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" $((2 - $(gconftool-2 --get "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode")))"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted! The call for switching works perfect.

Comment: But a question: I tried to map it to 'Super + H', but that doesn't work. However, with 'Ctrl + Alt + H' it works fine. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: It's probably because the Super key is used for Unity shortcuts of all sorts (hopefully that will be customizable in Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 13.04, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid) the following commands should work for you.

To enable launcher auto-hide setting use:

```
dconf write "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode" 1
```

To disable it use:

```
dconf write "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode" 0
```

Answer (score 3):

### For Unity

The command to make the launcher autohide:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" --type string "1"
```

And the command to make it never hide:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" --type string "0"
```

---

### For Unity-2D

To autohide launcher:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 1
```

To never hide launcher:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 0
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this seems correct but the changes don't seem to apply unless I open up the launcher settings window. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: @Joe No idea. If I set a keyboard shortcut, it seems to adjust the value. I don't know why the launcher is not reacting though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I created an application indicator called Unity Launcher Toggle that lets you switch between launcher modes. http://napdivad.com/unity_launcher_toggle/

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it for Ubuntu 16 or 17: (Based on falconepl & htorque's answer)

(This **toggles** the auto-hiding of launcher)

```
dconf write "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode" $((1 - $(dconf read "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode")))
```