# How do I enable and disable the Unity 3d launcher's auto hide setting with the terminal? (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, command-line, launcher, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut to change Launcher 'Hide' setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41241/shortcut-to-change-launcher-hide-setting)

Question says it all. I'm looking to make quick toggling icon basically.