# How to remove the Unity launcher icon by setting its size to zero?

Tags: 12.10, unity, launcher

Is there a way (on Ubuntu 12.10) to manually set the launcher icon size to 0 to permanently hide it? I hate the launcher after they removed dodge windows and I'm using Cairo now for my dock.

Comment: Do [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/41241/62483) solve your problem?

Comment: No, that's for 11.10 and below which has dodge function

Comment: possible duplicated: [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/q/38009/62483)

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate. In my comment to chad's answer I already stated I could hide it but I want the size to be 0, if we could edit the size down to 32 there must be a way to edit it down to 0

Comment: And what will be the difference (in terms of results) in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cairo dock installed (specifically `cairo-dock-data`) installed then when you log in you can click the ubuntu symbol to the right of your username and select the entry `Cairo Dock (GNOME)` or something to that effect. Enter in your password and when you log in your desktop will not have Unity and instead will just have Cairo Dock.

Hope this helps

Comment: I want unity's top bar I just don't want the side launcher, I realize I can set it to autohide and reveal sensitivity to none, but I don't want to see it when I open dash or drag icons around.

Comment: So let me get this straight you want to open the dash but you dont want unity?

Comment: I want to use unity just not the "Dock" on the side.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. It is especially annoying for me because I have two monitors and my mouse keeps getting "stuck" while moving from right to left.

Comment: So you want the dash but not the dock then? Either way, no matter what you want, it is impossible