# Launcher window dodge doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, launcher

In two accounts I have the launcher set to "Dodge Windows" (confirmed via CCSM). However, in one account it doesn't work, the launcher is stuck open as though I'd selected "Never".

I found some hints about this on other AU questions (which I can't find again right now :( ) which involved:

- logging out and in again
- pressing the Super key
- installing CCSM and changing the setting
- deleting some files in my home directory (can't remember which)

None of these have changed the launchers behavior.

What could be wrong in my misbehaving account?

This is not related to [a specific application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51496/unity-launcher-bar-stuck-and-wont-hide) nor [workspaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41962/what-to-do-when-unitys-launcher-gets-stuck-open) (I don't have any windows open in any other workspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to know which Unity you're using (3D or 2D), because changing your settings in CCSM achieves nothing if you're accidently using Unity 2D. I was using Unity 3D in one accoun and 2D in another (doh!)

There are limited ways to [configure Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d), otherwise switch to Unity 3D if possible, and [configure that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity) instead.