# How to make Unity Launcher menu be almost always hidden and not influence window placement

Tags: unity, launcher, window

I'm using Unity on 11.04.
I've had a look at the compiz-config settings but could not find any answers.

I would like to change a few default settings in Unity Launcher.

I would like to apply settings so that:

- Launcher is **only** displayed when I press the Ubuntu Button (or the Super Key) (or move the cursor to the top right of the screen). I.e., it is hidden even when there are no windows obscuring it.
- Launcher does not influence placement of windows (i.e., Unity should happily position a window aligned flush with the left side of the screen instead of defaulting to making space for the launcher)

Comment: I just realised that I'm not the first person to post this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install [Compiz Config Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
   [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] from the *Ubuntu Software Center*
2. Open **Compiz Config Settings Manager** from Dash
3. Find **Unity** plugin and change **Hide Launcher** to *Auto-Hide*