# Can I get the unity bar to not hide?

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

Title explains. Please help as I don't like not being able to see it the whole time.