# Unity launcher bar stuck and won't hide

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, drag-and-drop

When using drag and drop the launcher bar reveals and will not hide unless I close the program.

Is their a fix?

Comment: will you please explain what actually happened?

Comment: @shantanu I face the same issue when running java based programs, Such as Netbeans. If one of the windows (in netbeans e.g.output, tasks) dragged this is a sure thing to happen. This happened with LibreOffice - Draw but i couldn't reproduce it. Dragging other component of a program e.g firefox tab or desktop icon do solve the matter

Answer (score 13):

Run this in a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
unity --replace
```

That works for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: BEWARE!  This worked for me, but crashed a number of running applications, including firefox.

Answer (score 12):

Drag a desktop icon a bit.

Helps against the stuck launcher bar with Opera on a 32-bit system. Another solution would be to set the launcher not to hide in the first place (that's my solution for now). See [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

There are also bug reports:

- Opera: [bug 741731](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/741731) (note the "Won't Fix" as it's a bug in Opera)
- [Another one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/724986) - not sure what's the actual status on this one.

Comment: I ran into the "not hiding anymore" Unity/Gnome Ubuntu dock/launcher as well and found this answer here to be really helpful: just move one of the icons on the launcher a bit - that seems to reset autohide. At least for me, the Unity-dock resumed autohide afterwards. (I don't know why the dock autohide stopped in the first place, could be some hibernation cycles..)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue on 14.04.  It seems this can happen with the four-finger slide gesture.  If this is the case, simply do a four-finger slide to the left to slide the bar back into place.

Comment: works on 16.04!

Answer (score 5):

Its not uncommon for the launcher to get stuck. Opening the dash with the <kbd>Super</kbd> Key seems to fix it for me and its way better than killing a program.

If you can reproduce it, you might want to post a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 3):

Same problem when using Netbeans (Java) : when I drag tabs to reorganize them, the launcher appears and gets stuck (ie wont hide anymore).
Could not fix the problem, but found 2 solutions :
- drag and drop Firefox tabs around
- drag something to the laucher

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after I moved icons around and opened the dash with the super key. I simply logged out then logged back it. Fixed it right up.