# How to auto-hide Unity launcher faster?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

I can easily adjust the delay for showing the launcher with "edge reveal timeout" in CCSM.

How can I similarly adjust the speed for auto-hiding the launcher?

I want the launcher to hide as soon as my mouse moves away from it instead of having the current ~500ms delay.