# Why is DASH DISPLAYED permanently using screen space in the new V12

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

I have an Acer Aspire ONE Netbook and now having just upgraded to 12.04 the DASH program - that has always irritated me by keep popping up when I use spreadsheets and other documents that need the pointer to move close to the left edge of the screen causing the wretched Icons from DASH to pop up - is now PERMANENTLY down the side of my left hand side and as a result my internet pages all need scrolling to the right to get see the 1/4 inch pinched by DASH.  How can I get my screen back to full view and DASH at least in 'pop up' status again. If I am stuck with this then I will reformat my hard disk and either go back to UBUNTU version 9 which was much quicker starting and simpler to use or look for another Linux provider.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about the Launcher - the bar on the left hand side.  The default is 'Always show'.  You can change to 'Hide' in system settings->appearance->behaviour.