# Autohide question

Tags: window-manager, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

I have a ten inch screen, and Firefox is crowded to the right by what people seem to be calling the left Unity panel, so I have to slide the window to see the end of line. I wish to make this panel vanish and the full screen be covered by Firefox. (Clicking on the little box at the top of Firefox makes it smaller, not larger.) I am not sure this is an Autohide question, but it is a window manager question. The post numbered 132796 about Autohide was marked closed because it duplicated another; but I could not find what to click on to see the other.

Comment: If you [revisit the post you found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132796) today, you'll find that it's been closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/) - to reach it, just click the link under "Possible duplicate" =)

Answer (score 1):

Robert,

assuming you are using 12.04 **and** your system can handle 3D mode. Click on the top-left corner icon > System Settings > Appearence. Choose the *Behavior* tab and switch-on the *Autohide Launcher* option.

I'm not sure at this moment if this is also possible in 2D mode as I would need to end my session to check that.

If your system can run 3D, install MyUnity which will also let you to reduce the size of the launcher icons and gain some screen realstate.

Comment: >>Click on the top-left corner icon<< Oops! I meant the top-RIGHT corner icon (power/system).