# How to make browsers re-adjust web pages because of the sidebar?

Tags: launcher, chromium, browser

It does get annoying sometimes. Chromium has to make a bottom scroll bar for pages because the web pages are configured for the whole screen, and all because of the side application launcher bar. Anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect. More right is "Chromium has to make bottom scrollbar because web pages has tuned for bigger size than current size of monitor (or window)" ...

Solutions:

**0** You can use ***System Settings > Apperance*** ( 12.04 ) to adjust Unity to hide sidebar. Read this question: [*How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior?lq=1)

**1** Using wider monitor.
**2** Disabling any sidebars.
**3** Use special userstyles to override site styles (`width:100% !important` ) <sup>* Thanks for @Izzy</sup>
**4** Change zoom level. **Ctrl+MouseWheel** to zoom/out. **Ctrl+0** to reset.<sup>* Thanks for @erdemkeren</sup>

Comment: **4** notify web site admin to adjust/change the design. Guess I'm not the only one with the opinion fixed-size width for the entire page are problematic (elements like images are a different case). There are still users out there using monitors smaller than 22" :)

Comment: hm, yes. but each time users wants push more and more and more into :D

Comment: **5** Use special userstyles to override site styles. That's what I do for several Amazon sites; e.g. their partnernet pages sometimes also have an absolute fixed width, which I simply replace by `...width:100% !important` -- and with that they fit perfectly :)

Comment: @Izzy : if you like you are free to edit answer, welcome.
Rule 5 solution pretty nice instead 3.

Comment: 6 Change zoom level. May be try "ctrl + 0" if you already changed.

Comment: @swift Good suggestion, you are right. I added it as separate answer with more detailed information. Zoom is another possibility, sure -- as long as your eyes match the font size ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser used, suitable user-styles might provide a solution. For Firefox, there is the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/stylish/) addon for this issue, which I am familar with (I do not use Chromium). On the other hand it looks like there's a [Stylish for Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) available as well.

so how does that help you here? You first need to identify the "over-sized" element on the page. In many cases, this is a `div` element with the id "content" (`<DIV ID="content" ...>`), with a corresponding style saying something like `div#content { width:1234px ... }`. Using Stylish, you can override this setting, in my example this could be done by a user-style containing `div#content { width:100% !important; }` (the "important" meaning: override existing rule). With this relative value, that element now should always exactly fit into the window -- however, there may be more elements you need to adjust.

Before starting to play around yourself -- especially if you are not that used to HTML/CSS -- you could check at [UserStyles.ORG](http://userstyles.org/) whether somebody else already did that job. You will find a lot of interesting snippets there.

Alternatively / Additionally, it's worth taking a look at [UserScripts.ORG](http://userscripts.org/) as well. Instead of CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) they use JavaScript, which is "injected" into the pages at runtime. For Firefox this is done via Extensions like [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/scriptish/) -- as far as I know this functionality is built-in with Opera and Chrome, not sure about Chromium. Due to JavaScript usage, this way it is possible to manipulate the entire DOM-tree: add/delete/move elements, and more.