# Unity launcher no longer autohides after upgrade

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

After upgrading, Unity launcher is now always "active" whereas it used to auto-hide.

[image]

How can I change this panels properties so that it auto-hides again?

Comment: Can you see if setting the autohide works? http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior

Comment: [http://askubuntu.com/a/106673/45156](http://askubuntu.com/a/106673/45156) answered my question.