# Unity launcher doesn't reappear automatically -- 12.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: unity, virtualbox

I have reopened the Unity launcher by disabling auto-hide, thanks to this post -- https://askubuntu.com/a/106673/42720

I am running 12.04 in VirtualBox, and have tested this in both full-screen and windowed mode.  Moving the mouse to the left side, or top-left corner, of the Ubuntu desktop does not make the Unity launcher reappear.  I'd really like to be able to use this feature because I have a small laptop monitor.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Probably related to Virtual Box mouse integration, the mouse will be "released" to the guest machine as soon as it pass the screen edge, while Unity is expecting that you "press" it against the border. Have you tried to change the reveal sensitivity?

Comment: Yes, no luck with the change in sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Do yo have an nvidia card by any chance? Check out this bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1056555

Comment: Actually not; it's VirtualBox on a Macbook.