# How to autohide the Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

In Unity there is a Launcher on the left. One can easily change settings so that it hides automatically and appears only if the mouse cursor hits the left border of the screen (this is what I did).

Today, I pressed some button accidentally and the panel appears again and stays there. The main problem is that it covers the left parts of all my applications (for example terminal, so I cannot type in my terminal if it is maximized).

I tried to change the behavior in System Settings (the same window where I changed the background of the screen, but it has no effect).

Comment: panel ? did you mean Unity panel ? what desktop your using ?

Comment: I mean the stripe on the left that contain browser symbol, terminal symbol and symbols of other programs that I use. I do not know the terminology... I have reloaded the system. Now it works as before.

Answer (score 42):

Which OS version you are using, here answer in reference for 12.04 which I am using,

1. click on **setting** icon on right-upper corner of screen
2. Select **System setting**,
3. Select **Appearance** Icon
4. Select **Behavior** tab, under behavior tab **SWITCH-OFF** the Autohide Launcher option

For More reference see [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/q/9865/67654)

Comment: I used this procedure to change the behavior of the launcher (it hides and reappears only if I put cursor of the mouse to the left border of the scree). But it appeared once and did not want to disappear. The way that you mentioned did not work. The only thing that helped is reloading of the system.

Comment: @Roman, please try SWITCH-OFF the Autohide Launcher option, as I update my answer.

Comment: Another comment is you have to swing upwards for the auto show to work properly on 12.04. If you just hover on left side of screen, the panel won't show.

Comment: @JohnMerlino I have 16.04 and it won't show unless you move the mouse as you describe or continue to move the mouse 'past' the edge of the screen relatively far.  The mouse doesn't actually go off the screen, but moving it in that manner eventually causes it to show.

Comment: user **super** + **q** to show the hidden launcher

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 18.04 using Ubuntu or GNOME desktop environments:

1. Open up the *Settings*, which can be done by clicking the icon on the Dock (if available), opening the menu in the upper-right corner of the screen and then clicking the tools icon, or clicking on the *Activities* menu and searching for "settings".
2. In the left pane of the Settings window, click on the *Dock* option.
3. Toggle the option *Auto-hide the Dock* from OFF to ON.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:-

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

then under

**unity > launcher > select/deselect auohide**
now the launcher will autohide as usual