# Error with missing Wallpaper after remove unity from sudo command

Tags: sudo, desktop-background

After I paste these scripts into terminal, my wallpaper became white.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/xdg/xdg-une/autostart/maximus-autostart.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo ln -s /etc/xdg/xdg-une/autostart/netbook-launcher.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gconf/une/default/20_une-gconf-default /usr/share/gconf/defaults/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gconf/une/mandatory/20_une-gconf-mandatory /usr/share/gconf/defaults/
sudo update-gconf-defaults
```

Help me, I dont know what [-s] for ? and how do i get my wallpaper back.

Best Regards from Newbie

Comment: What for you enter those commands?

Comment: @ karthick87 I wanna remove unity bar, and google for it. Found in here http://askubuntu.com/questions/6418/how-can-i-remove-the-unity-launcher/19960#19960

But after restart, backround became white

Comment: Found the source here > http://maketecheasier.com/unlock-gnome-panel-in-ubuntu-netbook-edition-une/2010/04/25

Comment: Is this in 10.10 or 11.04?

Comment: on the ubuntu perfect ten 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ln -s will make a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to a file. To reverse what you have done just delete the links:

```
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/maximus-autostart.desktop 
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/netbook-launcher.desktop 
sudo rm /usr/share/gconf/defaults/20_une-gconf-default 
sudo rm /usr/share/gconf/defaults/20_une-gconf-mandatory 
sudo update-gconf-defaults
```

That should leave the system in the state that was prior the commands.

Comment: Thanks 4 d answer. Next time i will be more carefull. Maybe some backup needed

Answer (score 1):

It's so funny that i solved my own question. LOL
.
So, after long googling i decided to remove mutter with this commands
sudo apt-get remove unity

And everything goes perfectly