# Can I remove (or hide) the Unity launcher?

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6418/how-can-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

I want to remove the launcher from the left side of the screen completely (or at least hide it) and not pop up when I hover with the mouse.